# Drawing function with 3 variables using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to produce this: [image]

Function is: f(x,y,z) = x+y+z over S, where S is a part of unit sphere in first octant.

I tried:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function = {
            Z(\x,\y,\z) = \x + \y + \z;
        }
    ]
    \begin{axis}
    [
    axis lines=center,
    enlargelimits,
    tick align=inside,
    domain=1:1:1,
    samples=20,
    minor tick num=5,
    ]
    \addplot3 [surf] {Z(x,y,z)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I failed. Can someone help?

Comment: take a look @http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Comment: In a 3d plot you can only plot functions of 2 variables.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! In a 3d plot you can only plot functions of 2 variables. But this is precisely what you need here. You can just use standard polar coordinates to get

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function = {rx(\x,\y)=R*cos(\x)*cos(\y);
            ry(\x,\y)=R*sin(\x)*cos(\y);
            rz(\x,\y)=R*sin(\y);
            R=1;
        }
    ]
    \begin{axis}
    [view={140}{20},
    axis lines=center,
    enlargelimits,
    tick align=inside,
    domain=0:90,
    samples=20,
    minor tick num=5,
    point meta=-z
    ]
    \addplot3 [surf,shader=interp,opacity=0.6] ({rx(x,y)},{ry(x,y)},{rz(x,y)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. This is very nice solution, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @aurora you're welcome!